# ADODB RecordSet to string variable VBA

Tags: vba, ssis, adodb, recordset

Quick question about ADODB recordset. I want to extract a query result from a recordset and set it to a string variable:

```
query = "SELECT Value1 FROM Table"
RS = New ADODB.Recordset
RS.Open(query,Conn)
```

The query is always going to return 3 values. I want take to assign these three values to a variable. RS.GetString returns the query results tab delimited, but I want to be able to iterate through this set and assign each row result to its own variable. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the tables columns by name through the recordset.

```
Dim strValue As String
strValue = rs.Fields("ColumnNameHere").Value
```

As for looping the recordset

```
Do While rs.EOF = False

    strValue = rs.Fields("ColumnNameHere").Value
    msgbox (strValue)

rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

And if you are just learning looping. You'll at some point need to learn about `rs.MoveFirst`

Once you have been through your recordset and you want to go through it again for some reason you will need to move back to the beginning of the recordset before you can loop it again.

Recordsets also have `rs.Find` and `rs.Filter` and `rs.Sort`.

Lot's of good stuff.