# ADODB RecordSet to String() in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ado.net, recordset

I found this post which could help me in my project:

[ADODB RecordSet to string variable VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157320/adodb-recordset-to-string-variable-vba)

I want to adapt it to VB.NET instead of VBA, but it does not work.

My goal is to create a String() using SQL. To give you an idea how the string would look like if hard coded, this is how we do it:

```
Public Sub New()
InitializeComponent()
strValue = New String() {"10051", "65658", "25689" etc... }
End Sub



**'My actual code is as follows:**

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
Handles MyBase.Load

Dim Connection1 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Connection1 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RecordSet1 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim SqlQuery1 As String, ConnectionString1 As String
Dim strValue As String()

SqlQuery1 = "Select ItemCode From OITM"
ConnectionString1 = "Driver=SQL Server;Server=Myserver; Database=MyDbase; 
User Id = sa; Password= 12345"
Connection1.Open(ConnectionString1)
RecordSet1 = New ADODB.Recordset
RecordSet1.Open(SqlQuery1, Connection1)
strValue = TryCast(RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value, String())

Do While RecordSet1.EOF = False
strValue = TryCast(RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value, String())

MsgBox(strValue)
RecordSet1.MoveNext()
Loop
```

I expect the MsbBox to show the ItemCode at each looping, and building up the whole (very long) string. But it shows blank.

I read that probably EOF does not work in VB .NET.

What must I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problems:

First of all you are casting the value you get from the recordset to a String Array. Why? You shouldn't do it, try setting the value directly like this:

```
strValue = RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value
```

Second, you are not concatenating the string. Use "+" or "&" to concatenate what are you reading from each row like this:

```
Do While RecordSet1.EOF = False
    strValue = strValue + RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value

   MsgBox(strValue)
   RecordSet1.MoveNext()
Loop
```

But you need an Array for your needs. So you can use a list and then the toArray Method:

```
Dim strValues As String()
Dim strList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()

Do While RecordSet1.EOF = False
    strList.Add(RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value)
    RecordSet1.MoveNext()
Loop

strValues = strList.ToArray()
```

Now strValues is your Array Of String read from a SQL db.

Comment: of Autocomplete..................................In his example, he uses an array which is hard coded, like this:......................................Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()........
        collections = New String() {"William James", "Robin Hood", "David Copperfield", "Albert Einstein", "Me", "You", "Richard D. Feynman", "David Beckham", "Fermi", "Someone somewhere"}....

Comment: The question isn't why you are using an array (this doesn't matter), my question is: why are you tring to cast the value to string(): strValue = TryCast(RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value, String())? You shouldn't do it. Try setting it to without casting simply: strValue = RecordSet1.Fields("ItemCode").Value

Comment: ctd...As the string array is used in subsequent code, I have to generate a similar array (using SQL), else the modified program will not work. So, essentially my problem is this: How to generate a string array from SQL similar to the hard coded array in the example?

Comment: Did you try using the separator and the split function? as i showed you in the answer? Or the list?

Comment: Sorry. I type slowly, and after 5 mins, I cannot edit my thread. I hope you can understand. Please ask for more info. Next time, I'll type in Word and copy to this forum :)

Comment: @LeonLai You can still edit your original question. It's only comments that lock. Pasting from Word is not a great option.

Comment: @Babbillumpa. Your solution works perfectly for me.Great! I am now trying the other suggestions posted by others, and will let them know.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect the MsbBox to show the ItemCode at each looping, and building up the whole (very long) string

That's just not how it works. Each time through the loop, you have **one item**. Nothing in the code accumulates the values from each iteration. Attempting to cast as an array, even if it would work (which it doesn't) would still only give you a *new array instance* on each iteration with just that one item. And again, even this much doesn't happen. You can't just cast a single item as an array.

More than this, .Net uses **real** arrays, not the array-like collections you see in other languages now. .Net has those collections, too, but it doesn't try to pretend they are arrays. One of the key attributes of a real array is a **fixed size**. You must know the number of elements in the array when you first allocate it. Even `ReDim Preserve` relies on this, effectively allocating a *whole new array* and copying all the elements every time you use it. This means it's really strange to expect casting an item to an array variable will concatenate to the array. It sounds like you may want a `List(Of String)` instead of an array.

If other parts of your program expect an array, you will want to change them to use the `List(Of String)` instead. Basic arrays are not used as often any more in .Net, mostly replaced with generic `List(Of T)` types. And whenever possible, make your method parameters ask for `IEnumerable(Of T)` instead of `T()` or `List(Of T)`. When you use `IEnumerable(Of T)`, both arrays and lists can be passed as arguments.

Another issue is using an array with `MsgBox()`. The message box is not smart enough to know what to do with an array. You end up falling back to the `System.Object.ToString()` overload, which just returns the type name. So even if everything else worked (which it won't), the best you could hope to so see is the text `System.Array`.

Finally, **don't use RecordSet in VB.Net**

The old ADO library only exists for backwards compatibility when porting code forward. You shouldn't use it in new development. Use the newer ADO.Net API instead.

Try this:

```
'At the very top of the file:
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Handles MyBase.Load

    'I know this is just a sample, but DON'T USE THE SA ACCOUNT!
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Server=Myserver;Database=MyDbase;User Id=sa;Password=12345"    
    Dim Sql As String = "Select ItemCode From OITM"

    Dim result As New List(Of String) 'The "array" (really an array-like collection)
    Dim message As New StringBuilder() 'For building up the string

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
          command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)

        connection.Open()
        Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
            Dim delimiter As String = ""
            While reader.Read()
               Dim itemCode As String = reader("ItemCode").ToString()
               result.Add(itemCode)
               message.Append(delimiter).Append(itemCode)
               MessageBox.Show(message.ToString())
               delimiter = ","
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Another option is to create a DataTable:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) 
    Handles MyBase.Load

    'I know this is just a sample, but DON'T USE THE SA ACCOUNT!
    Dim ConnectionString As String = "Server=Myserver;Database=MyDbase;User Id=sa;Password=12345"    
    Dim Sql As String = "Select ItemCode From OITM"
    Dim result As New DataSet()

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString), _
          command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection), _
          adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)

        adapter.Fill(result)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: I just tried your first code. It works perfectly for me. Why do you recommend DON'T USE THE SA ACCOUNT?